# automatic method POST or PUT in laravel form collective

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I am using [laravel form collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html) for automatic form generation in project. 
I used same form for add and update with route model binding

```
{!!  Form::model($operator, ['route' => ['operator.update', $operator->id]])  !!}
```

and route for this is

```
 Route::resource('operator','OperatorController');
```

This generates automatic routes for method like `POST` for store and `PUT`  for updates

if I use form collective then by default method is `POST` for both store and update 
if I change to `PUT` then it changed for both

I need automatic method detection like if I am using for store, it should be `POST` and `PUT` if it is edit form

can we do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Mainly if you want to detect both of this situation you should use `Form::open` for create mode and `Form::model` for update mode (with method `PUT`) like this:

```
@if(!empty($operator))
    {!!  Form::model($operator, ['route' => ['operator.update', $operator->id], 'method' => 'PUT'])  !!}
@else
    {!!  Form::open(['route' => ['operator.store', $operator->id]])  !!}
@endif
```

This above will automaticlly add `_method` hidden field to your form (with PUT value) on updating.
You should also split for to actions (`store` and `update`) as it's in Laravel Docs about [Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers).

Comment: yes we can do that like this also 
`@if(!empty($operator)) 


  <input type='hidden' name="_method" value="PUT" />


@endif `

Comment: so does this helps?

Comment: Thank you, this is a good reference on the otherwise hard to find, how to pass a route parameter, when using a named route, when using laravel html collective.